# Angular | Pass parameter to multiple components when navigate

Tags: angular, components, parameter-passing, router

I Have this structure in my application:

```
<div class="container">
    <top-navbar></top-navbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <navbar></navbar>
</div>
```

So, I have the TopNavbarComponent, the router-outlet, and the NavbarComponent.

Then I create the HomeComponent and the AboutComponent.

Let's say that I want to navigate from Home to About like this:

Path definition:

```
{ path: 'about/:parameter', component: AboutComponent },
```

In HomeComponent I do:

```
this.route.navigate(['/about', 'a parameter'])
```

My question is this: **How can I pass parameter to TopNavbarComponent?**
so i could get it like this:

```
this.activated_route.snapshot.params['parameter']
```

from TopNavbarComponent

Is there any way or I should follow another approach?

> Solution does what I want but if anybody has an answer to go like I
>   proposed it's welcome

Comment: You can use a shared service or listen route changes in `TopNavbarComponent`

Comment: Could you post a solution please, i am new to angular and i don't quit catch what you are proposing. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Have you tried pass input? `<top-navbar [param]="value"></top-navbar>` and receive it in parent component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use query params

```
this.router.navigate(['/about'], { queryParams: { page: pageNum } });
//will give host-address/about?page=2
```

Or

```
this.router.navigate(['/about', { id: aboutId, foo: 'foo' }]);
 // will give host-address/about;id=15;foo=foo
```